# matplotlib.pyplot how to add labels with .clabel?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I use pyplot.clabel to attach the file names to the lines being plotted?
`plt.clabel(data)` line gives the error

Answer (score 0):

Helou,

plt.clabel is only used with contour lines, according to documentation: "adds labels to line contours in cs, where cs is a ContourSet object returned by contour ([axes_api](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html)). Please check [contour example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/plot_directive/mpl_examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.py):

Answer (score 0):

You may use `plt.annotate` or `plt.text`.

And, as an aside, 1) you probably want to use different variables for the file names and numpy arrays you're loading your data into (what is `data` in `data=plb.loadtxt(data)`),

2) you probably want to move the label positioning into the loop (in your code, what is `data` in the `plt.clabel(data)`).